# Clairaut's equation: Find the general solution of $x^2 (y-xy') =y(y') ^2$ if the singular solution doesn't exist.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Question:
Find the general solution of

$$x^2 (y-xy') =y(y') ^2$$

if the singular solution doesn't exist.

Now, I know that it has to be solved by Clairaut's equation.

However, the given equation is not of the form $y=px+f(p)$ where $p=y'$ and cannot, as far as I know, be reduced to this form.

I even tried arranging the equation in the form of a quadratic in $y'$ but when I find the solution it yields a rather big equation that doesn't really lead anywhere.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite the equation as
$$x^2 \left(y-\frac{x}{x'}\right)-\frac{y}{x'^2}=0$$ Now, let $x=\sqrt{y z}$ which makes
$$\frac{y^2 z \left(y^2 z'^2-z^2-4\right)}{\left(y z'+z\right)^2}=0$$ Excluding the trivial solution, we are left with
$$y^2 z'^2-z^2-4=0$$ that is to say 
$$\frac{z'^2}{z^2+4}=\frac 1 {y^2}\implies \frac{z'}{\sqrt{z^2+4}}=\pm \frac 1y$$ which seems to be simple to integrate.

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be yz'+zy' when you substitute for x or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MadCap. Since $y$ became the variable, $y'=1$. I double check and all of this seems to be correct.

Comment: Oh now it's more clear.