# Find the non singular solution of this ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution of the differential equation $$x^2\left(y-x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$ which does not contain the singular solution.

I used Clairaut's method. I assumed $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $p$ then continued. But then the calculation was too complicated and I don't know how to proceed further. It was messy and leading to nothing. How to solve this$?$

The answer given is $y^2=cx^2+c^2$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015235/clairauts-equation-find-the-general-solution-of-x2-y-xy-yy-2-if-the) can help you.